# How to set precedence of dynamic routes in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

Following two path match the same pattern, I fill in the browser field: `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/organizations/xyz` and Next.js does not load the 2nd but the first, why? How can I give priority, force one route over the other?

```
pages/[postId]/[tempUserShortId]/[imgId]/index.tsx

pages/dashboard/organizations/[organizationShortId]/index.tsx
```

Shall I use a 'bridge' page which expect 3 parameter? If first parameter is `dashboard`, pass to second component, else, to first?!

What is the usual way to handle this situation?

Comment: Have you tried entering http://localhost:3000/dashboard/organizations/xyz ? otherwise maybe you can create pages/dashboard/[organizationShortId]/index.tsx ?

Comment: ahh yes, `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/organizations/xyz`

Comment: In Next.js, predefined routes already take precedence over dynamic routes. Navigating to `/dashboard/organizations/xyz` will route to the `pages/dashboard/organizations/[organizationShortId]/index.tsx` page. See https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats.